# Generate radio buttons in vue.js by using v-for

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, radio-button

I want to generate radio buttons in vue.js by v-for, but when they are generated if i selected one radio the rest radios is selected too, so i want user to be able to choose only one radio.'

```
<template>
 <div> 
  <div v-for="item in items">
      <input type="radio" id="l1"  value="item.text" v-model="checked">
      <label id="l1" for="item.text">{{item.text}}</label>
  </div>
 </div> 
</template>
```

Comment: Add a colon `:` before `for` to tell Vue to interpret its contents as a js expression instead of as a string: `<input type="radio" :for="item.text">`. Do the same for `:value="item.text"`. It's a shorthand for `v-bind:for` and `v-bind:value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio-1) value.

As you didn't bind value, radio button values are all same as the fixed value - `item.text`, not the dynamic one `${item.text}` which is the `text` value of `item` object.

---

`for` attribute of `label` tag is the id of the form element to be bound.

```
  <div v-for="item in items">
      <input type="radio" :id="item.text" :value="item.text" v-model="checked"> // `:value` is shorthand for `v-bind:value`
      <label :for="item.text">{{item.text}}</label>
  </div>
```